# How to call a function defined in a PL/SQL package with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

If you create a plain old function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(p_bar_i IN VARCHAR2) RETURNS VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN p_bar_i || 'baz';
END;
/
```

You can call it in `sqlalchemy` easily:

```
q = session.query(func.foo(MyTable.hello))
# or
sel = select([func.foo(my_table.c.hello)])
```

How can you call a function defined inside a package from SQLAlchemy, like the following:

```
CREATE PACKAGE master
IS
    FUNCTION foo(p_bar_i IN VARCHAR2) RETURNS VARCHAR2;
END;
/
CREATE PACKAGE BODY master
IS
    FUNCTION foo(p_bar_i IN VARCHAR2) RETURNS VARCHAR
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN p_bar_i || 'baz';
    END;
END;
/
```

Comment: `func.master.foo(MyTable.hello)`